# How to not make Enter key being added as a string using react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement wordle like functionality where I update the currentGuess to be whatever is entered.

```
function App() {
  const [guessWord, setGuessWord] = useState(Array(6).fill(null));
  const [solution, setSolution] = useState('');
  const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState('');
  const [isGameOver, setIsGameOver] = useState(false);
 useEffect(()=>{
    const handleType = (event) => {
      if(isGameOver) {
        return;
      }
      if(event.key === 'Enter') {
        if(currentGuess.length != 5) {
          return;
        }
        //add the guessed word to the guessWord array and then set currentGuess to be empty
        let newGuess = [...guessWord];
        newGuess[guessWord.findIndex((val) => val == null)] = currentGuess;
        console.log('currentGuess', currentGuess);
        setGuessWord(newGuess);
        setCurrentGuess(' ');
        const isCorrect = solution === currentGuess;
        if(isCorrect) {
          setIsGameOver(true);
        }

      }
      // if word length exceed the length 5 return
      if(currentGuess.length > 5) return;
      if(event.key === 'Backspace') {
        setCurrentGuess(currentGuess.slice(0,-1));
        return;
      }
      setCurrentGuess(prevGuess => prevGuess + event.key);
    };
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleType);
  
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleType);

  },[currentGuess, isGameOver, solution, guessWord]);
```

In addition to the string, when enter key is pressed the word adds 'Enter' string to the currentGuess as well and adds it to the next guess. I am unable to debug as to how to avoid Enter being added to setCurrentGuess. Please help me understand it.

[image]

Comment: I think all you need to do is return early when you get an enter (so you won't append the character to the guess)